# Deadlock while updating two different rows on a single table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Been reading on deadlocks alot and when i thought i knew it well here comes the problem.

There are two similar transactions going on at same time. They look like below:

```
BEGIN TRAN //read_committed_snapshot ON

//an application sends insert query
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('Name',15)

//later on application sends update query for the newly inserted row
UPDATE t1 SET name='NewName', number=16 WHERE id = 10 //this ID is the id of the inserted row. 

COMMIT
```

The given code is not the exact one that i use in my app, but the idea is same, it just has more columns.

Table t1 has primary key ID, some nonclustered indexes.

After running two of these transactions simultaneously it deadlocks. The profiler says that the deadlocked query was this `UPDATE t1 SET name='NewName', number=16 WHERE id = :id` for each of the conflicting processes.

Sorry i do not have the XML of the deadlock, but profiler told that both processes had X lock and both of them tried to acquire U locks.

```
process 1
owner - X
waiter - U

process 2
owner - X
waiter - U
```

`t1` table was shown for both processes as object and PK_id index as `indexname`.

So what is actually happening here? Each transaction updates different rows in same table, why did it deadlock?

Many examples on the net say 'hey its because of how it scans indexes, it scans pk index for one transaction and some other nonclustered index for another transaction' but their profiler deadlock graphs show different values under `indexname`, so that is not the same as i am having, the index name is the same.

Any ideas how to resolve this? Its driving me crazy. I thought enabling read_committed_snapshot would solve this but i was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely that one or both of your updates using the table/clustered index **scan** for find the rows for update - it often causes deadlocks. Check the execution plan.

Comment: But it already acquired exclusive locks, which i would understand are key locks of the rows being updated. Whats the point of trying to place update locks on anything other than the two rows in question. I will check the execution plan when i am able(tho i get lost there quite easily still)

Comment: There will be Intent locks on table and page, and since table has indices - queries may interfere on updating indices as well